# Python Table to JSON with a hrefs included

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im new to Python and been trying to learn both Python and BeautifulSoup.

Ive been searching stackoverflow for some solutions but I can't seem to figure out how to also grab the `a href` on the `td` of a `table`.

This is what I have so far, was edited to meet my needs from another post. How would I incorporate the `a href` links as other `"key":"value"` into the json object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

html = """<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/page/some-page">Some Page Title</a></td>
        <td class="created-at">2020-08-01</td>
        <td><a href="/id/400">Text Description 1</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><a href="/page/some-page-2">Some Page Title 2</a></td>
          <td class="created-at">2020-08-02</td>
          <td><a href="/id/400">Text Description 2</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><a href="/page/some-page-3">Some Page Title 3</a></td>
          <td class="created-at">2020-08-03</td>
          <td><a href="/id/400">Text Description 3</a></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"""

data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.select('table > tbody > tr')

for table in rows:
    keys = ["Name","Date","Description"]
    values = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in table.find_all('td')]
    d = dict(zip(keys, values))
    data.append(d)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

I basically need to add 2 more to keys and get the `a href` values:

```
keys = ["Name","Date","Description","Url1","Url2"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello How Are you? Hope this is what you want.

```
for table in rows:
    keys = ["Name","Date","Description",'Url1','Url2']
    values = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in table.find_all('td')] + [a.attrs['href'] for a in table.find_all('a')]
    d = dict(zip(keys, values))
    data.append(d)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Some Page Title",
        "Date": "2020-08-01",
        "Description": "Text Description 1",
        "Url1": "/page/some-page",
        "Url2": "/id/400"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Some Page Title 2",
        "Date": "2020-08-02",
        "Description": "Text Description 2",
        "Url1": "/page/some-page-2",
        "Url2": "/id/400"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Some Page Title 3",
        "Date": "2020-08-03",
        "Description": "Text Description 3",
        "Url1": "/page/some-page-3",
        "Url2": "/id/400"
    }
]
```